# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '""' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: php, poo

estoy aprendiendo de a poco algo de POO. Tengo dos archivos.
En el primero es donde creo los atributos y en el segundo pruebo la clase.
Tengo el error del titulo en el segundo archivo (donde pruebo la clase creada)

//Primer archivo

```
<?php

    
    class Alumno

    {
        
         @var string
        private $nombre;

         @var string
        private $apellido;

         @var string
        private $email;

         @var int
        private $legajo;

         @var DateTime
        private $fecha_nacimiento;

        

        public function setNombre($nombre){

            
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }


        
        public function getNombre(){

            return $this->nombre;
        }
    }
```

Segundo archivo:

```
<?php



    require_once 'Alumno.php';


    

    $ari= new Alumno();

    $ari->setNombre(nombre  "Ariana"); //linea del error

    echo $ari->getNombre();
```

Comment: La estructura del código que muestras es insuficiente para saber qué tratas de hacer. Debes incluir más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Te haré los siguientes comentarios:

1. La sintaxis para documentar tu código, debería ser alguna de las siguientes opciones:

   - 1.1 Uso de [*DocBlocks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docblock)
   - 1.2 Desde [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#attributes) se incorpora la sintaxis de *atributos*

El punto anterior te lo comento por que a como lo tienes al momento te va a generar un *error de sintaxis*

2. **Aunque no es determinante** para el problema que expones, considera que si usas una versión [mayor o igual a la 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties) ya puedes trabajar con *propiedades tipadas*, es decir indicar el tipo de dato de cada atributo de clase.
3. **Este punto tampoco es determinante** para el error mostrado, pero considera que si usas [una versión mayor o igual a la 7](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) entonces puedes usar las declaraciones de tipo de devolución en tus métodos.
4. Finalmente, el otro error que tiene tu código, es que colocas *lo que parece ser una variable* (pero con una sintaxis errónea) como argumento del método **`setNombre`**, pero no es necesario ya que en este punto solo debería recibir el *argumento* para el parámetro que tiene en su declaración; pero aún así recomiendo [repasar la sintaxis válida de declaración de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.basics.php#language.variables.basics)

**Ejemplo**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class Alumno
{
    /** 
     * El nombre del alumno en cada instancia
     * 
     * @var string $nombreAlumno 
    */
    private string $nombreAlumno;

    /** 
     * Establece el nombre para el Alumno
     * 
     * @param string $nombreAlumno 
     * @return void
    */
    public function setNombreAlumno(string $nombreAlumno): void
    {
        $this->nombreAlumno = $nombreAlumno;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el nombre del Alumno
     * 
     * @return string
    */
    public function getNombreAlumno(): string
    {
        return $this->nombreAlumno;
    }
}

$nuevoAlumno = new Alumno();
$nuevoAlumno->setNombreAlumno('Alguien');
echo $nuevoAlumno->getNombreAlumno();
```

> Esto que te dejo es un ejemplo de como se podría desarrollar el código de tu pregunta, aunque por ejemplo estaría pendiente el *namespace* al que pertenece la clase.

**Lecturas extra**

- [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)
- [Referencia de tags](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/index.html)